# Unclear how to read cookie properties and use in conditionals -

Tags: cookies, js-cookie

I'm using [js-cookie](https://%20https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie):

It's easy to set a cookie, but I'm unclear how to output specific values and test against them. This works fine:

```
Cookies.set('newsletter', 'show', { expires: 30, path: '/' });
var myCookie = Cookies.get('newsletter');
```

But this does not:

```
if(myCookie){
  var p = Cookies.get(['expires']);
  document.write(p);
}
```

How do I access the `expires` property?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/issues/723) it is not possible

> It‘s not possible.

Also in the [FAQ](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#why-wont-you-let-me-get-a-cookie-with-a-particular-attribute-say-path-or-expires) it states the same thing:

> It's not possible. Once the cookie has been written, its attributes
> can‘t be read out. The underlying API we‘re constraint to use doesn‘t
> support this:
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie